# Resume from suspend not working on Macbook Pro 5,5 with Nouveau

Tags: 12.04, suspend, macbook-pro, nouveau

Resume from suspend used to work perfectly on my Macbook Pro 5,5. I was using the Nvidia graphics driver, which had really bad support for OpenGL, so I purged the Nvidia driver switched to the open source Nouveau driver. Now OpenGL rendering is blazing fast, but my computer never resumes from suspend. It still suspends fine, but when I try to resume, after 30 minutes, all I see is a garble screen. I have to perform two hard-reboots to restore the system.

I checked my disk and memory to make sure it wasn't a hardware fault, but they both check out, leaving me to suspect it's something wrong with the driver. Unfortunately, since I have to reboot, all the logs are being cleared, so I have no idea how to find an error message or how to debug this.

How do I figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue may just be trying to use the non-Nvidia drivers. I have an HP laptop that refuses to resume after hibernate in the same way as your Mac Book unless I install the proprietary drivers.

Comment: I just tried the Nvida 331 driver, and that made things even worse. That caused no desktop at all to show even after a reboot.